# How to construct a certain subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{R})$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, abelian-groups

Consider the real $2\times2$-matrices that (with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$ represent rotation around the origin over $120$ degrees and reflection in the $x$-axis. Construct the smallest possible subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{R})$ containing these two matrices. Is the resulting group abelian? Find the order of each element of this group.

How do I have to start? Never got this kind of questions before, the lecturer gave me a terrible explanation and there's nothing to find in the lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

You start exactly as the question describes; first write down these matrices explicitly. Then look at the subgroup they generate; what do the products of these matrices look like? And their inverses?

While fiddling around, I would advise you to keep in mind the geometric picture of how the matrices act on $\Bbb{R}^2$. That avoids a lot of computations.

---

**EDIT:** To make the fiddling around part more concrete; consider an equilateral triangle in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with one vertex on the $x$-axis, and the other two symmetrically above and below the $x$-axis. Now it is easy to verify (both visually and by linear algebra) that the given matrices permute the vertices of the triangle. How many ways are there to permute the vertices in total? And can you get all permutations by applying some combination of these matrices?

Comment: I shall try it. Thanks. Only not sure if I am capable of doing this because the only courses I had before were basic calculus courses. (first-year mathematician). Never seen something like this before and I am stuck on the question the whole day already.

Comment: Then I hope you have at least seen the definition of a group, and what 'abelian' and 'order' mean, as these don't usually show up in basic calculus courses.

Comment: Yes, I found those defenitions on the internet. Problem is not knowing how to start, I tried youtube for visualization the problem, but that did not help me either.

Comment: Assuming from your name that you can read Dutch, I can recommend a few sections from [this reader](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/algebra1.pdf); for the definitions see the first two pages of chapter 2. For an illustrative example, see section 2 of chapter 1 (*symmetrieën van de ruit*). This section treats precisely your question (except that you might want to consider an equilateral triangle in stead of a diamond) and assumes no prior knowledge of groups.

Comment: Yes I can read Dutch. Thankyou, I will take a look at it.